# Unable to use img ng-src (Can't bind to ng-src since it isn't a known property of img)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have an Angular project with Webpack, and I am trying to use an img tag with ng-src, per the Angular docs here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

I am trying to have a variable in the image source like so:

```
<img ng-src="assets/images/{{row.imagePath}}.png" width="1" height="1" />
```

However, when I run ng serve, I get the following errors in the browser console:

```
zone.js:569 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-src' since it isn't a known property of 'img'.
```

I have Googled and found others using ng-src without issues with Angular + Webpack, so I am not sure why it is not working in this project. Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `[attr.src]` input to bind to native html properties.

**In your component.ts file**

Lets say you have a list of items of type `ListItem`, the `ListItem` class would need to expose an `imagePath` property. Like so

```
export class ListItem {
    public imagePath: string;
    // ....
}

@Component({
  templateUrl: './your/template/example.html',
})
export class YourComponent {
    listItems: ListItem[];
    //...
}
```

**In your template**

```
<div *ngFor="item in listItems">
    <img [attr.src]="item.imagePath" width="1" height="1" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Where is one supposed to find the list of bindable attributes of a HTML tag? a search for "img" on angular.io is not giving me comprehensive docs on it..

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was using just src.
Example:

```
    <td><img src="assets/{{elemento.foto}}" alt="(sin foto!)" class="img-responsive"/></td>
```